# jqgrid export data to pdf and excel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I am developing jqgrid in my php yii application. I want to export grid data to pdf and excel. in the other words, I want to export exact current table(with filters and sorting) to pdf and excel. many solutions i tried but no result :(
For example I see [this page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/export/pdf/default.php) for pdf export, but did not help me. and also add `$("#list").navGrid('#pager', {refresh: false, edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, pdf:true, excel: true});` to my script but no luck.
can anyone help me to solve this problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: can you post complete code for jqgrid and what issue are you facing right now ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding excel: true just shows the button, you need to add the exporting code to the php as well. Have a look at this working example
http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/export/excel/default.php

Answer (score -1):

I dont see where any of these examples actually show how to make this work?
if you add something like this

jQuery("#acct_list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{excel:true,add:false,edit:false,del:false});

and this
jQuery("#acct_list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{
       caption:"To Excel"});

you get a button with a caption.. but nothing else.

i dont see in the examples what actually makes the data get exported

http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/export/excel/default.php this shows an example. what in this code causes the download to happen? i dont see any calls to other code?